# Alternatives to HMAC + CBC?

Tags: encryption, cbc, hmac, database

I'm looking at using HMAC + CBC. The combination looks like this:

```
ciphertext = AES256(text, k1)
data = HMAC-SHA256(iv | ciphertext, k2) | iv | ciphertext
```

Where:

```
k1 = 32 byte key - Randomly generated, once
k2 = 32 byte key - Randomly generated, once
iv = 16 bytes - Randomly generated, for every message
```

The purpose is for storing sensitive information in a database.

Is the above approach cryptographically secure for sensitive information? Would there be any reason to consider a stream-cipher mode verses a block-cipher mode like CBC?

Would an [AEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEAD_block_cipher_modes_of_operation) mode like OCB or CCM be more appropriate?

If an AEAD mode is not available for the platform we are using (specifically [Go](http://golang.org/)), is it worth the effort trying to implement these modes?

Comment: I imagine things would be easier if you moved the HMAC to the end. $\:$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, at the record level.  (What you've built would be classified as a "Encrypt-then-Authenticate" scheme in the literature, and there are standard provable security results for such schemes.)  Well done on constructing a solid, well-engineered cryptographic scheme.

An AEAD mode would spare you from having to invent such a scheme, but what you've got is fine, and there's no reason why you need to change.

There's no reason to switch to a stream-cipher mode of operation.

As others have mentioned in the comments, this would be more secure if you included an identifier in the input to HMAC that identifies the table, row, and column where this appears, so that a ciphertext cannot be replayed from one position to another.  There will still be the risk of rollback attacks, as fgrieu explains; that is more challenging to defend against, so if you need to stop them, you might want to elaborate on the specific application situation.

Comment: One issue I can see is how this database is structured. For instance, if he is encrypting a single field, then an attacker could forge data by copying the value of one field to another. So, I think (if this is the case) there should be a row-unique identifier included in the authenticated data, probably the auto_inc column for the table. Also, the scheme is vulnerable to "replay" attacks, is it not...?

Comment: Indeed, the scheme is solid at the record level. I second @Reid's comment: each record's integrity is protected, but the database's integrity is not. Adding an identifier of the record's location in the HMAC helps, by preventing moving records, but it still allows rolling back each record of the database to an earlier state. Even if we link the update of records in some way, the database as a whole can still be rolled back.

Comment: Is there some reference material I can look at about these replay issues? The database is not accessed directly. If the attacker has direct access to the database, wouldn't he also have access to the ids? Also is there any benefit from separating the signature out into a separate column, or is it better to keep it mixed in with the ciphertext?

Comment: Also, in the database context: while the confidentiality of each record is protected, the location of updated records is not. And the atomicity of the updates of multiple related records (e.g. update of accounts in a manner preserving the overall balance) is not protected.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you separate out the signature into a separate column or not.

Comment: @Luke: If the attacker does not have "direct access to the database" or an equivalent mean, why do you want to encipher each record, and protect their integrity with a keyed scheme? You may need authenticated and enciphered access to the database, and this is NOT the same as authenticating and enciphering each record.

Comment: @fgrieu: The database can only be accessed by an intermediary. The intermediary is protected by SSL w/ CA signed client/server certificates. Information can only be retrieved by an entity with a signed client certificate, and will only respond if provided with a proper object id (non-sequential). Still, I want to consider as many attack vectors as I can. The MAC is for protecting against a padding oracle IF the database was compromised. Adding the id makes sense, I'm just unsure about how to handle roll-backs. Any suggestions / white-papers / articles would be helpful.

Comment: To defend against rollback attacks, it seems you often must have a trusted process with trusted memory, which might be a hard pill to swallow if the adversary has write-level access to the database. You might look into buying write-once memory to store versioning info. But at some point your software budget grows thin, and you have to accept that there may indeed be attacks which can roll back the state of the application. However, with frequent backups and sanity checks (with the write-once memory), you can mitigate the potential effect of rollback attacks on your organization.

Comment: As a bit of encouragement, though, even if the attacker can roll back the state of your database, he shouldn't be able to read the data at all assuming your keys are stored somewhere safe. (Of course, hopefully an adversary with write-level access to the DB can't get your keys, or else you may have problems...)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insights! You've brought up some good concerns and things for me to think about.